# Get Malformed Image Data

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, blob, png, jpeg

When the browser realizes that an image is corrupt / not following `.jpg`, `.png` (etc..) format the browser displays this icon:
[image]

```
<img src="some_malformed_img.jpg" onerror="errorHandler()" id="Img1" />
```

In JavaScript how can I get the malformed image data? This is what I've tried:

```
function errorHandler() {
  var c = document.createElement('canvas');
  var img = document.getElementById('Img1');

  c.height = someHeight             //Let's assume I know the height
  c.width = someWidth;              //Let's assume I know the width

  var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, c.width, c.height);

  var base64String = c.toDataURL(); //<---- This is empty :(
}
```

For this example, we are assuming the server actually sends the file and that it's just the browser that determines that the file is malformed.

Comment: I'm confused. Do you believe your browser is wrong in determining a certain image file is malformed, and so you are attempting to draw it anyway? Do other browsers agree the file is bad? If you store it locally and test it for correctness using other tools, is it bad?

Answer (score 1):

If the browser determines the image is corrupt you will not be able to draw it to a canvas also the drawing and the saving step may not be lossless so you probably will not have the same data the server sent.
If you really want to get the image data just do an ajax request

```
function errorHandler() {
    fetch(document.getElementById('Img1').src)
    .then(function(response) {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("HTTP error, status = " + response.status);
        }
        return response.arrayBuffer();
    })
    .then(function(image_data) {
    // do something with the image data
    });

}
```